# C++: Is it possible to manipulate whole matrices rathen than individual elements?

Tags: c++, matlab

This question appeared while I was making Conway's Game of Life.
In C++, I did things this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            int neighbours = 0;
            for (int yKord = i - 1; yKord <= i + 1; yKord++)
                for (int xKord = j - 1; xKord <= j + 1; xKord++)
                    if (xKord != j || yKord != i)
                        if (xKord >= 0 && xKord < size && yKord >= 0 && yKord < size)
                            if (mat[yKord][xKord] == 1)
                                neighbours++;

            newmat[i][j] = 0;
            if (mat[i][j] == 1)
                if (neighbours == 2 || neighbours == 3)
                    newmat[i][j] = 1;
            if (mat[i][j] == 0)
                if (neighbours == 3)
                    newmat[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            mat[i][x] = newmat[i][x];
```

But in matlab, you can use this approach:

```
N = 100;
T = 50;


X = rand(N, N) > 0.5;

figure(1); imagesc(X); axis image; colormap gray; drawnow;
for t=1:T
    neighbors = circshift(X, [1, 0]) + circshift(X, [-1, 0]) +  circshift(X, [0, 1]) +  circshift(X, [0, -1]) + ...
    circshift(X, [1, 1]) + circshift(X, [-1, 1]) + circshift(X, [1, -1]) + circshift(X, [-1, -1]);

    X(find(((neighbors > 3) | (neighbors < 2))  & X)) = 0;
    X(find((neighbors == 3) & ~X)) = 1;
```

I wonder if it is possible to use this approach in c++, manipulating the matrix all at once.

Comment: `std::valarray` or some library to use matrices. Matlab is a language specifically made for data manipulation, so it's natural that it has such functionality built-in, C++ is a general purpose language.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_linear_algebra_libraries

Comment: Please [edit] your code and properly indent it

Comment: You may want to look at the C++ [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) library. They have made good efforts to make it _Matlab like_.